# PyMongo MapReduce always using floats

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, pymongo

I'm trying to use mapreduce, but it converts integers into floats for some reason.

Map:

```
function() {
    emit(this._id.p, 1);
}
```

Reduce:

```
function(key, values) {
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        total += values[i];
    }
    return total;
}
```

I get an output like this:

```
[
    {u'_id': 1.0, u'value': 6.0}, 
    {u'_id': 2.0, u'value': 6.0}, 
    {u'_id': 3.0, u'value': 5.0}, 
    {u'_id': 4.0, u'value': 6.0}, 
    {u'_id': 5.0, u'value': 3.0}, 
    {u'_id': 6.0, u'value': 6.0},
    **snip**
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Javascript doesn't have a notion of "integer," all numbers are floats. So your `emit(this._id.p, 1)` statement is emitting the float 1.0. MongoDB provides a `NumberInt` and `NumberLong` class to the Javascript interpreter to work around this.

Try `emit(this._id.p, NumberInt(1))` instead.